# Android face detector using android camera

Tags: android

I've read its possible to use the built in android face detector to find the position of faces in a bitmap. Does anyone know of any examples of doing this using the camera as an input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible with the Face Detection APIs in ICS. Refer the camera section on this page:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html

You must register a `FaceDetectionListener` and then call `camera.startFaceDetection()`. Please read the link above for more details.

I wrote some sample code. It isn't perfect since its Work In Progress but the face detection bit works just fine:

https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B2Nu5U2Cz81qZExGQ25sWVdRd21IOExUUTZsZzFoZw

Comment: I know face detector is available in earlier API levels than ICS, is there a reason this is limited to ICS?

Comment: Face Detection from the camera preview is a new feature in ICS. It also depends on the chipset's camera drivers. Sometimes, new useful framework components like Fragments etc are released for earlier version using the compatibility package but I don't see that happening for face detection (from preview) APIs.

Comment: Oh okay got it. Thanks for all the help. One last question so i tried running it on my newly upgraded asus transformer and it crashes every time giving me an error about 0 faces. Is there any way to fix this? I thought maybe switching cameras may help, i posted the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578097/android-face-detection-maxnumdetectedfaces

Comment: There is an older face detection capability that goes back to API 1. It's called [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html) and it doesn't require hardware support so it's available on all phones.

Comment: @Christian it seems it works only if the image is already created , and not while the camera preview is "running" . is it possible to show the detected faces while the camera preview is "running" , even on old APIs ?

Comment: @android Not with the older API that I know of. You have to use the new API for that.

Comment: that's too bad . however i think i do remember that some camera apps have this feature , maybe even of samsung?

Comment: Guys, is there a possibility to constantly scan for eyes' activity?

Comment: Existing quesiton: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15380889/scanning-eyes-activity-with-android-facedetector-face-api

Comment: Does this actually draw a rectangle around the person's face? Not working for me.

Comment: Note that there is now a new face detector available:  https://developers.google.com/vision/