# is Android 4's face detection API dependant on specific phones?

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, face-detection

I'm trying to develop a face recognition system for Android, and I opted to use Android 4 as it has the built in face detection API. I'm using a Samsung nexus s and despite being as up to date as possible and a really new model phone the .getMaxNumDetectedFaces() method returns 0.

Am I doing something wrong or can this phone actually just not detect faces? 
I thought the face detection would be included in the Android software and not the phone specific software.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two different face detection APIs in Android. [FaceDetectorListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.FaceDetectionListener.html) which depends on getMaxNumDetectedFaces() is hardware dependent so it might not be enabled on phones even if they run the latest version of Android. [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html) on the other hand runs in software and is supported since Android 1 so you might try that. Another option is to install [OpenCV for Android](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html).

See also, the answers on this question: [Android face detection MaxNumDetectedFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578097/android-face-detection-maxnumdetectedfaces/10552040#10552040)

Comment: I will try that thanks. 
Is OpenCV for Android a ported version of OpenCV? because what I am doing at the moment is importing the c++ OpenCV library as a native library

Comment: Yeah, it is ported by the OpenCV team specifically for Android. A co-worker is running it and it looked pretty fast. This doesn't help you but apparently if you are running it on a Nexus 7 or Galaxy Nexus it uses hardware acceleration...

Comment: that is pretty cool, I will have to look at upgrading my app to use it in the future