# Android Ice Cream Sandwich tablets that support Face Detection

Tags: android, face-detection

I'm trying to build an application for android tablets that uses androids new face detection which is only compatible with ICS and up. I upgraded my Asus transformer to ICS but I don't believe it supports Face Detection. Does anyone know of any tablets that have or can be upgraded to ICS that do support Face Detection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your camera (front facing) works, it is built into ICS http://www.gottabemobile.com/2011/12/15/how-to-setup-face-unlock-on-android-4-0/

As far as coding for it:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html

and

http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/news/2011/10/first-look-android-40-sdk-opens-up-face-recognition-apis.ars

So hardware restriction should be minimal. Code away and test!

Also: some examples pre ICS [Face recognition API for java android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825778/face-recognition-api-for-java-android)

**EDIT** After reading through all your similar posts:

[Android face detection MaxNumDetectedFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578097/android-face-detection-maxnumdetectedfaces)

[Android face detector using android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569529/android-face-detector-using-android-camera)

I assume you are running a ROM and there is probably a driver or kernel issue preventing yours from working, but the device does support it as most would:

http://www.androidauthority.com/install-android-4-0-on-asus-transformer-with-face-unlock-working-revolver-rom-57840/

Try a different ROM and use one that is known to work. Then that problem is solved and you can start coding and finding more problems ;-)

If you are not running a ROM and you upgraded to Stock ICS for the Asus Transformer...it looks like they broke it: http://www.mobileinquirer.com/2012/asus-transformer-missing-face-unlock-feature-unlocked-but-risks-associated/ and you'd be better off rooting the device if you want to use it for testing and debugging.

Comment: Well right now I have ICS on my original transformer and when using the front facing camera i always get an error in logcat saying faces supported = 0

Comment: Are you running a ROM or stock? Can you edit your question and include some logcat errors?

Comment: All the details are in this question, Thanks for the help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9578097/android-face-detection-maxnumdetectedfaces

Comment: Updated my answer, it sounds like your specific ROM doesn't work. It must be a driver/kernel issue. Your device does support it and I assume most will.

Comment: Thank you so much! I was about to go out and buy a new tablet because i thought it was the device and wasn't getting any information anywhere, when i get home today i plan on trying out that ROM and reporting back, Thank You!