# Object recognition with android using OpenCV library

Tags: android, object-recognition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where do I start learning about image processing and object recognition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432569/where-do-i-start-learning-about-image-processing-and-object-recognition)
>   [Is there any best way for implemeting Object Recognition in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13682406/is-there-any-best-way-for-implemeting-object-recognition-in-android)

I tried to implement object recognition(Face tracking) in my project using OpenCV library, But I have a problem with openCV when I run this application on my device it require to install OpenCV Manager in your device.

I just wanted to know is there any way to do object recognition without install any external application or supporting file in device.

Comment: This might help you:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9569529/android-face-detector-using-android-camera

Comment: @hotveryspicy yes that was my first question and i am new in stackoverflow, I never used before.

Comment: Thank's for reply Anand Sriraman but this is for android 4.0(ICS) or above version's of android. I wanted to do for 2.3 or 3.0 above android version's.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could try the [FaceDetector](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.Face.html) class. Its available since API Level 1.

Comment: face detector and recognition are different things, you should delete this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try attach native libraries for OpenCV to your project and use `OpenCVLoader.initDebug();` to initialization.